# How to scrape data from javascript environment that don't have any table in its source?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a code to get into a javascript environment, then I want to scrape the data from the website using BeautifulSoup. The point is that I realized that there isn't any table in the environment, so I was wondering about how can I scrape the data from the website.

Any tips?

This is for my completion of coursework and I've tried to scrape the data wondering that there was a table, but it has failed.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import os

url = "https://scon.stj.jus.br/SCON/legaplic/toc.jsp?materia=%27Lei+8.429%2F1992+%28Lei+DE+IMPROBIDADE+ADMINISTRATIVA%29%27.mat.&b=TEMA&p=true&t=&l=1&i=18&ordem=MAT,@NUM"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[16]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

pagina_de_resultados = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

table = pagina_de_resultados.find_all('table')

df = pd.read_html(str(table), header=0)

datalist.append(df[0])

x += 1

driver.quit()

result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(datalist[i]) for i in range(len(datalist))], ignore_index=True)

json_records = result.to_json(orient='records')

print(tabulate(result, headers=["Processo", "Relator(a)", "Órgão Julgador", "Data do Julgamento", "Data da Publicação/Fonte", "Ementa", "Notas", "Informações Complementares à Ementa (ICE)", "Referência Legislativa", "Jurisprudência Citada", "Acórdãos Similares"], tablefmt='psql'))

path = os.getcwd()

f = open(path + "\\fhsu_payroll_data.json", "w")
f.write(json_records)
f.close()
```

I expected that the output was a table with the judgement infos, but instead I got the error that there was no table found in the environment.

Comment: is it legal ? :)

Comment: Yes, Gees. I want to get infos about judgements and that info is public. Actually, I was going to scrape this manually, writing the infos in Excel, but I think it's way better to do it by Python.

Comment: Are you expecting those 13 points short summaries?

Comment: @QHarr I am expecting that all of those fields, indicated in `print(tabulate(result, headers=[...]))`, is copied to a table from the website mentioned above.

Comment: There isn't a table tag on https://scon.stj.jus.br/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?livre=%28lei+ou+norma%29+com+%28%278429%27%24+ou+%278.429%27%24+ou+%27008429%27+ou+%27lei+de+improbidade%27%29+com++art%24+adj5+%28%2717%27+ou+%2700017%27%29++prox2+%28%28par%24+adj2+%28%276%27+ou+%276%BA%27+ou+%2700006%27%29%29+ou+%27%A7+6%27+ou+%27%A76%27+ou+%27%A7+6%BA%27+ou+%27%A76%BA%27%29&&b=ACOR

Comment: @QHarr I know. I'm wondering how to scrape that data, assuming that there is no table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the tags associated with the data you want, and dump that into a dataframe. Here's the first page/link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import os

url = "https://scon.stj.jus.br/SCON/legaplic/toc.jsp?materia=%27Lei+8.429%2F1992+%28Lei+DE+IMPROBIDADE+ADMINISTRATIVA%29%27.mat.&b=TEMA&p=true&t=&l=1&i=18&ordem=MAT,@NUM"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[16]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
pagina_de_resultados = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = pagina_de_resultados.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

results = pd.DataFrame()
for each in paragrafoBRS:
    if each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip() == 'Processo':
        header = []
        content = []

    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

    df = pd.DataFrame([content], columns = header)
    results = results.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: how could I force a line break when it comes to "Processo" again, so I don't get hundreds of columns with the same name? Or how do I merge those columns to have multiple lines instead of multiple columns?

Comment: ah ok. My mistake. Not sure why i did that. I'll fix that

Comment: Ok fixed it. But keep in mind since not all columns headers are present on each page, you'll have sparse data

Comment: Nice! I’ve got those columns I told before, but the code only scrape data from one decision. LOL